# How to save multiples match in one column? rvest, R and stringr

Tags: r, rvest, stringr

This question is a sequence to the problem [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70826317/how-to-save-result-as-nd-when-there-is-no-record-rvest-and-r)

I have these two example html: [url1.html](https://prequest.websiteseguro.com/example/url1.html) ; [url2.html](https://prequest.websiteseguro.com/example/url2.html)

The u[rl3.html](https://prequest.websiteseguro.com/example/url3.html) is another example with more IPC

In URL2.html there is no information (51) and in URL1.html there is.

I'm using this code in R:

```
library(rvest)
library(tidyverse)
library(stringr)

x<-data.frame(
    URL=c(1:2),
    page=c(paste(readLines("url1.html"), collapse="\n"),
                 paste(readLines("url2.html"), collapse="\n"))
) 

for (i in 1:nrow(x)){
    html<-x$page[i]%>% unclass() %>% unlist()
    read_html(html,encoding = "ISO-8859-1") %>% 
        rvest::html_elements(xpath = '//*[@id="principal"]/table[2]') %>%
        html_nodes(xpath='//div[@id="classificacao0"]') %>%  
        html_text(trim=T)%>%  
        str_replace_all(.,"[\\n\\r\\t]+", "")%>%
        stringr::str_trim( ) -> tmp
    
    if(length(tmp) == 0) tmp <- "ND"
    x$ipc_0[i] <- tmp %>% str_replace_all(.,"\\s+", " ") %>% str_replace_all(.," \\)", "\\)")
}

for (i in 1:nrow(htm_temp)){
    html<-x$page[i]%>% unclass() %>% unlist()
    read_html(html,encoding = "ISO-8859-1") %>% 
        rvest::html_elements(xpath = '//*[@id="principal"]/table[2]') %>%
        html_nodes(xpath='//div[@id="classificacao1"]') %>%  
        html_text(trim=T)%>%  
        str_replace_all(.,"[\\n\\r\\t]+", "")%>%
        stringr::str_trim( ) -> tmp
    
    if(length(tmp) == 0) tmp <- "ND"
    x$ipc_1[i] <- tmp %>% str_replace_all(.,"\\s+", " ") %>% str_replace_all(.," \\)", "\\)")
}
```

Result: partially correct

[image: Output]

Desired result:create a new dataframe with the following structure.

| URL | IPC |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | B62B 1/16 (1968.09)... |
| 1 | B62B 1/00 (1968.09)... |
| 2 | ND |

**Problem: There are url`s that have the code (51) and others that do not. When you have the code (51) the structure can contain "n" id with the following structure xpath='//div[@id="classificacao0"]. the Rating Id can contain values from 0 to "n". How to optimize this code to capture the necessary information without having to do a lot of for (variable in vector) for each "n"?**

**Any idea how to solve this problem?**

Comment: `css='div[id^=classificacao]'` might work

Comment: @QHarr, But this also brings up the tags with id="classificacaocpc[0:n]"? How to differentiate?

Comment: `css='div[id^=classificacao]:not([id^=classificacaoc])'`

Comment: @QHarr,grateful! Any ideas on how to generate the desired result?

Comment: Not without spending time working through what actual final result should be. Your stated desired result looks like it has only two fields with urls repeated row wise for where multiple IPCs present? Also, where does the 1968.09 come from? I didn't see it on the page?

Comment: For example, 1968.09 is at url1.html in xpath( "/html/body/form/div[2]/div/table[2]/tbody/tr[6]/td[2]/font/div[2 ]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/font/b")

Comment: Does the declared desired result appear to have only two fields with repeated inline URLs for where multiple IPCs are present? Yes, because these two IPC for example belong to this url "patent"

Comment: @QHarr,grateful! 
The last problem I have is how to get the information (71) following the same procedure. building a table similar to that of the IPC but for DEPOSITOR. Do you think it's better to open another question or can you add the solution to this question? If so, I would just adjust the problem presented for cases (51) and (71). Can be?

Comment: @QHarr, To save the corresponding IPC definition add an IPC_INF column in the table, would it be like?

Comment: I'm lost as to what the new requirement is. Can you not apply the same logic as below if trying to do for DEPOSITOR?

Comment: @QHarr, I'm at a loss for the new requirement. Can't you apply the same logic below if you're trying to do for DEPOSITOR? Unfortunately not, because: 1) dynamically generated page (a time can be tr[20] like tr[12]; 2) In this tag there is no id or class that helps to filter we have to look directly at the html_txt and 3 ) there are patents that will have the information (71) and others will not. That's the difficulty.

Comment: That definitely warrants a new question with your current attempt and a full explanation.

Comment: @QHarr, ok. So this question is finished.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use css attribute = value css selector list with ^ starts with operator to capture/exclude elements with specific id and id values.

Convert your current extraction code into a function which accepts (in this case) an url as argument. Extend the regex to remove the other characters not shown in your desired output.

Have that function return a tibble of url and ipcs found; wrap the whole thing in a `map_dfr()` call to generate a single DataFrame result.

```
library(rvest)
library(tidyverse)

urls <- sprintf("https://prequest.websiteseguro.com/example/url%i.html", 1:3)

get_ipc <- function(url) {
  ipc <- read_html(url, encoding = "ISO-8859-1") %>%
    html_elements("div[id^=classificacao]:not([id^=classificacaoc]) .normal > b") %>%
    html_text(trim = T) %>% 
    str_replace_all(.,  "[\\n\\r\\t]+|\\(|\\s{2,}|\\)", "")%>%
    stringr::str_trim()
    if(length(ipc) == 0) ipc <- "ND"
    return(tibble(url = url, ipc))
}

df <- purrr::map_dfr(urls, get_ipc)
print(df)
```

---

[image]